# Rearranging column of a data frame in desired order in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-structures, structure

I have a data frame as below and want to change the order of its columns. I want the columns in order as: 1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6. How can I reorder this? Note that this is a small example and I have many more columns where I want to order them like this. The general formula would be 1+3x for the first batch, 2+3x for the second and 3+3x for the last one, where x=0,1,2,....

````
dput(medg)
structure(list(X1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 
2, 3), X2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), 
    X3 = c(2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 
    3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), 
    X4 = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 
    1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), 
    X5 = c(0, 0.2622587, 0.1040687, 0.1409907, 0, 0, 0.6184543, 
    0.9525439, 0.7830234, 0.3400703, 0.2622587, 0.6184543, 0.3765996, 
    0.907851, 0.5296791, 0.1040687, 0.9525439, 0.3765996, 0.5567241, 
    0.3325466, 0.1409907, 0.7830234, 0.907851, 0.5567241, 0.2221638, 
    0, 0.3400703, 0.5296791, 0.3325466, 0.2221638, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -36L))
```
````

Comment: Can you explain more about the general solution you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may create a `matrix` to rearrange the column order

```
medg[c(matrix(seq_along(medg), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE))[seq_along(medg)]]
```

---

Also, if we want to use the `3 *`

```
i1 <- rep(seq_len(ceiling(ncol(medg)/2)), each = 2) + 3 * (0:1)
medg[i1[seq_along(medg)]]
```

Comment: Thanks. Except that in the first part, instead of 2, I would put any number of nodes that I have. The second one I'm not quite sure how it'd work for more than 2 nodes.

Comment: @statwoman can you describe what you meant by `node`s here

Comment: Let's say I have more columns, so the order would be 1,4,7,2,5,8,3,6,9. This looks like I have three elements (nodes), each with three columns.

Comment: @statwoman perhaps the 2 should be `floor(ncol(medg)/2)`

Comment: @statwoman i think you need to specify the `ncol = 3` in the first case as a general case

Comment: @statwoman suppose your `medg2` have 9 columns `c(matrix(seq_along(medg2), byrow = TRUE, ncol = 3))#
[1] 1 4 7 2 5 8 3 6 9`

Comment: Or if it is 12 columns `medg2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(5 * 12), ncol = 12))
;c(matrix(seq_along(medg2), byrow = TRUE, ncol = 3))#
 [1]  1  4  7 10  2  5  8 11  3  6  9 12`